# Pressure changes in Continuity equations and Poiseuille's Law?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Continuity says Q=AV, and we know that velocity and pressure are inversely related. So if we are in a closed system, like vasculature for example, Q is constant and any decrease in vessel radius would be expected to raise velocity, which would result in *lower* pressure.

If we look at Poiseuille's Law, on the other hand, we see the opposite! If Q is constant, then a decrease in radius/cross sectional area we should expect pressure to *be raised*!

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernoulli is a statement of the law of conservation of energy for an ideal (non vicious) fluid. Poiseuille relates to situations where fluid friction is present so you cannot expect the results to be the same.

If you use Bernouilli for an ideal fluid through a  horizontal tube of constant cross sectional area, no pressure difference is needed across the tube to move the fluid through it, ie the fluid moves through the tube with a constant kinetic energy and no work needs to be done.
The situation changes if there is fluid friction and work has to be done to keep the kinetic energy of the fluid constant.
That work is done as a result of the pressure difference across the tube.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please clarify what you meant by that last line? Do you mean that the pressure dropping is 'doing the work' of keeping it flowing (I guess the right way to phrase that is 'providing the energy'...')

Comment: Yes. You have a net force on the liquid due to the difference in pressure and that force does work in moving the fluid through the tube. The liquid gains no kinetic energy and that that work ends up as heat due to the fluid having a viscosity.

Comment: So...one should use Poisseuille for times when friction (and therefore pressure) are relevant? And Q=AV...is only where pressure would not be changing?

Comment: If the density of the fluid is not changing the Q=AV is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Pressure always increases when velocity decreases (and vice-versa) only for an inviscid fluid.  If the fluid is viscous, then this is not necessarily the case.  For flow of an inviscid fluid through a pipe of constant cross section, the pressure is constant.  For flow of a viscous fluid through a pipe of constant cross section, the pressure decreases in the flow direction.  So, for a real viscous fluid, one of these two effects is going to win out.  That depends on the specific geometry of the conduit, the mass flow rate, and the viscosity of the fluid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this mean that Q=AV is only an approximation (ie, for inviscid fluids), but in the real world we should always use Poseuille?

Comment: For incompressible fluids (e.g., water, blood, etc.), you would use this equation, and Poiseulle is only valid for laminar flow at constant cross section (not turbulent flow).

Comment: Why would continuity suffice as long as it's incompressible? Is it because it for all practical purposes "overrides" the effects of viscosity and friction resistance?
Also, what about the in-between scenario: compressible, but turbulent?

Comment: If it is incompressible, $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0$

Comment: Oh...so are you saying that if we expect pressure to be constant, then we are free to use Q=AV. But if we expect it to change (for example, due to friction/resistance), then we need an equation to take that into account--and therefore use Poisseuille?

Comment: No.  Not at all.  I said nothing of the sort.

Comment: So then can you clarify what you meant when you said if it is incompressible, then there is no pressure change? I thought you were explaining that that incompressible=no pressure change=use Continuity...?

Comment: I never said that.  If it is incompressible, then there is no density change.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood delta-p/delta-t = 0?

Comment: That was a rho, not a p.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking vasculature then you might be coming to this question from a biomedical context, and of the physicists who frequent this place, I happen to be in a strangely unique position to correct a common misconception here. Let me phrase it this way:

**Flow and pressure are very different things.**

In the human body, blood *pressure* is just about the most routine medical measurement that you will find. Essentially, you squeeze a blood vessel in one point with lighter and lighter pressures until the force of the vessel against your squeezing is negligible, as usually verified by acoustics. Blood *flow* on the other hand requires sophisticated machines that [my dad's company](https://www.transonic.com/) happens to produce, though some of the sophistication is due to making these things non-invasive. (See e.g. cup anemometers.)

One flow approach, for example, clips a small pad containing two ultrasound transducers onto a blood vessel, with the other side of the clip serving as a reflector. By pulsing either transducer as an emitter, and running the other as a receiver, you get very accurate timing for how long it takes sound to bounce from the upstream transducer to the downstream transducer, versus how long it takes for it to bounce from the downstream one to the upstream one. The difference in these transit times tells you how the blood is flowing through the vessel, since the speed of sound in blood is constant in the frame where the blood is at-rest.

Now Bernoulli's principle does say that, all other things being equal, higher flow will lead to a pressure drop. Flow affects pressures, and pressures can also affect flow. But they are very different ideas and you will benefit immensely from keeping them mentally separated.

One obvious difference is that the pressure measurement is non-directional; it doesn't know anything about upstream or downstream -- squeeze the vessel in one place and you will get the pressure. Well if we're talking about the flow in a blood vessel, it really matters if it's going backwards or forwards! So nondirectionality immediately means that you're not truly measuring flow; the engineers at my dad's company *had* to create something which has an upstream and downstream component to be able to tell the difference. Well, we can fix that with our pressure sensors: we can measure two pressures in two places, one upstream of the other on a blood vessel. Generally, then, in healthy blood vessels we will see some variant of the Hagen-Poiseuille equation here: in its most abstract form it tells us that the flow's friction with the walls of the blood vessels leads to a lower pressure downstream than upstream. This effect gets more and more visible the farther and farther our pressure sensors are. And since we're talking about friction losses with the wall, it should not surprise you that if you drive the flow faster, these friction losses will be greater. Both pressures may indeed be *individually* lower due to the Bernoulli effect: but the pressure *difference* between the two points follows Hagen-Poiseuille and *must* be bigger simply because faster motions incur more friction losses with the walls.

But when I say that flow is conceptually very different from pressure, I'm also asking you to imagine, say, that we measure a blood vessel in a vertical orientation rather than a horizontal one: the blood flow will be the same throughout, but gravity increases your blood pressure going down. This is why, for example, gravity does not cause fluid flow in your cup of coffee; a pressure gradient immediately opposes it. OK, so now we've learned that our "2-point pressure gradient meter" definitely doesn't measure flow if the two pressure points are not totally horizontal! What else is the matter with it? I'm also asking you to imagine that the blood vessel is *not* healthy and that things are *not* normal.

So imagine if you will a blockage of the blood vessel. For the flow measurement, it doesn't matter if we clip this probe upstream or downstream or right on top of the blockage -- we see zero fluid flow through the blockage. That's a very simple result. What about the pressure measurement? Well, if both our probes are on one side of the blockage, we'll hopefully see a constant blood pressure, indicating that the Hagen-Poiseuille losses are being balanced out by something else, and we might guess that this is because those losses are 0 because the flow is 0. So it's not like we get *no* information, we just get *clumsy* information. It doesn't help that if we're looking for friction losses, we need to measure pressure at a substantial distance, which decreases the chance that both probes are on the same side of the blockage. What if they're on opposite sides, what happens there? Well, those two parts of the vessel are topologically disconnected: what happens to the pressures there depends on *the entire rest of the vascular system*! That blockage is able to absorb forces and possibly create its own forces on the fluids that are present in the vessel. You might expect a large pressure gradient, maybe the upstream side is immediately at much higher pressure than the downstream side, and we could detect this. But that's only one of many possibilities that the rest of the system could provide. Another possibility is that the blockage becomes totally invisible; say we see a "normal looking" pressure loss between the two vessels. Or we might see alarming things, like we might see a complete inversion of pressure where the "downstream" side is somehow at higher pressure than the "upstream" side. There's just no correlation, that's the problem. You can't diagnose zero-flow from any of these because they all could occur in the presence of zero-flow.

See, pressure is fundamentally about *forces*. These are often inter-atomic forces that are not immediately intuitive--but pressure is fundamentally about them. If you have a pressure gradient, then that is an immediate force on the fluid. By contrast, flow is about velocities. There's much to say here, like: due to the incompressibility of normal fluid flows, these velocities go inversely proportional to cross-sectional areas and the volumetric flow into a system is usually equal to the volumetric flow out of the system, unless the system is changing its state to release or absorb fluid from the system. But flow is fundamentally about these velocities.

So let me state this insight that flow and pressure are different in a more nuanced way. We know that $F = m \frac{dv}{dt}$ and that therefore forces will tend to change velocities, if nothing else is at play. So if fluid particles can flow freely, they start immediately to respond to imposed forces, and pressure gradients are an important one of those forces. They aren't the *only* such force, though: as we saw, you take a column of still water and the pressure at the bottom is greater than at the top, precisely so that the pressure gradient exactly balances the gravitational force and no flow happens. If you can eliminate these external forces and let a fluid flow freely, then yes, pressure gradients will perfectly correspond to flows. But when the fluid can't flow freely, pressure gradients and flows become very disconnected concepts; the pressures might have nothing to do with the flow precisely because there might be too many forces complicating the situation.